# Use relative path with -Xloggc

Tags: java, logging, collections, garbage

Is there any way to use a relative path with -Xloggc to set the path where the garbage collection events are written to? I have only been able to get -Xloggc to work with absolute paths.

Comment: Check the working directory from which your java application is started. Maybe the script that starts your app changes the directory before calling java executable and either that directory is not writable or your relative path points to non-existent path when in that directory.

Comment: That worked. I could have sworn that I checked in the working directory but I guess not. Thanks